# admob ads are not shown in real device

Tags: android, firebase, admob

This is my project build grade code

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app build grade code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.personal.numbermania"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    debug
            {
                debuggable true
            }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

Test ads are showimg up in emulator but no ads in real device.please help me

I followed below link to get ads
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

I followed below link to setup firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: kindly share logs whey you run it on actual device.

Comment: i cannot see my device when i click run method.I am manually installing apk file into device

Answer (score 0):

use ad unit id of particular category you have created in project in ad mob.

for ex you have created banner ad unit in you project- you will see ad unit id for banner in list use that ad unit id(you will see ad unit id below title you have given while creating banner ad).

For more info refer https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638 you will get what i am trying to explain.